# SQL (lite) Value Mapping

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple SQL table displaying Name (text) and Value (text). The value can be a int, float and string. And to my question, in some cases the value can have a mapping while all other cases the value shall be displayed as is. What is the proper SQL way to do this given that the db will contain several mapping tables.

take the following example:

Query raw:

```
temp1 , 3.2       (As is)
temp2 , 20.0      (As is)
Valve , 0         (map 0 / 1 to close / open)
Engin3, 1         (map 0,1,2,3 -> running, idle, stopped, off)
Sysflag, A        (As is)
```

query w Mapping:

```
temp1, 3.2
temp2, 20.0
Valve, Closed
Engin1, Idle
SysFlag, A
```

Thanks

Continue...

GMB, thanks for your feedback. I can see how handling the mapping with case query makes sense in the limited example I’ve given. For my IRL db I think making a mapping table is more appropriate. I also like the idea of a small query, but speed is prio 1 (running on embedded device). My level of SQL knowlage is bellow the level of defining clean sql table relations and rules, other than if the type is defined in the mapping table and the value is not defined, the value text shall display "error(value)".

So for my simple db example please help understand your last suggestion with mapping table and what I’m doing wrong:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS devtbl(Name TEXT, Value TEXT);
INSERT INTO devtbl VALUES('temp1'   , '3.2' );
INSERT INTO devtbl VALUES('temp2'   , '20.0');
INSERT INTO devtbl VALUES('Valve1'   , '0'   );
INSERT INTO devtbl VALUES('Engin1'  , '1'   );
INSERT INTO devtbl VALUES('System'  , 'A'   );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mappingtbl(Name TEXT, Value TEXT, Mapped_Value TEXT);
INSERT INTO mappingtbl VALUES ('Valve1' ,'0','close' );
INSERT INTO mappingtbl VALUES ('Valve1' ,'1','open'  );
INSERT INTO mappingtbl VALUES ('Engin1','0','running');
INSERT INTO mappingtbl VALUES ('Engin1','1','idle'  );
INSERT INTO mappingtbl VALUES ('Engin1','2','stoppe');
INSERT INTO mappingtbl VALUES ('Engin1','3','off'   );
```

Running the query results in the folloing output in sqlite3

```
select devtbl.Name, coalesce(devtbl.Value, mappingtbl.Mapped_Value) 
from devtbl left join mappingtbl 
on mappingtbl.Name = devtbl.Name and mappingtbl.Value = devtbl.Value;

Name        Value
--------------------------
temp1       3.2
temp2       20.0
Valve1      0
Engin1      1
System      A
```

Something not supported in sqlite3, wrong idea or wrong query?

Wanted result:

```
Name        Value
--------------------------
temp1       3.2
temp2       20.0
Valve1      Close
Engin1      idle
System      A
```

I was speculating of having a column in devtbl with a reference to the mapping table. In case mapping table reference exist then use mapped_value else display devtbl value.

DevTbl:

```
Name        Value       MappingRef
-------------------------------------
temp1       3.2
temp2       20.0
Valve1      0       ValveMap
Engin1      1       EnginMap
System      A
```

ValveMap:

```
Value       map_value
-------------------------------------
0   close
1   open
```

EnginMap:

```
Value       map_value
-------------------------------------
0   running
1   idle
2   stopped
3   off
```

Also if the Value does not exist in the mapping table, then display error. What would be the sq query for this case? What are the best, correct, clean and the most speedy sq way of doing this?

Comment: Your rules for mapping are not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the transcodification in a two-level `case` expression, like so:

```
select
    name,
    case name
        when 'temp1' then value 
        when 'temp2' then value
        when 'Valve'
            then case value
                when '0' then 'close'
                when '1' then 'open'
            end
        when 'Engin1'
            then case value
                when '0' then 'running'
                when '1' then 'idle'
                when '2' then 'stopped'
                when '3' then 'off'
            end
        when 'SysFlag' then value
    end
from mytable
```

You can *slightly* shorten the `case` expression as follows:

```
case 
    when name in ('temp1', 'temp2', 'SysFlag') then value
    when name = 'Valve'
        then case value
            when '0' then 'close'
            when '1' then 'open'
        end
    when name = 'Engin1'
        then case value
            when '0' then 'running'
            when '1' then 'idle'
            when '2' then 'stopped'
            when '3' then 'off'
        end
end
```

---

One way to *really* simplify this query would be to create a separate table to store the mapping, something like:

```
name        value        mapped_value
Valve       0            close
Valve       1            open
Engin1      0            running
Engin1      1            idle
Engin1      2            stopped
Engin1      3            off
```

You can then `left join` the mapping table in your query:

```
select t.name, coalesce(m.vaue, t.mapped_value)
from mytable t
left join mapping_table m on m.name = t.name and m.value = t.value
```

Comment: The `left join` option is brilliant.